# Echo in the first line printf '%s\n' however the \ symbol not printed

Tags: sed

i have the following set in file1

```
'a 1-61' 'a 7134-7194'
```

and I am trying to print at the beginning of file1 by

```
sed -e "1s|^|printf '%s\n'|" < file1 > file2
```

but I get

```
printf '%s
''a 1-61' 'a 7134-7194'
```

I do not know how to exclude the \ symbol so to make it work. The desire output would have been

```
printf '%s\n' 'a 1-61' 'a 7134-7194'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU sed interprets `\n` as representing a newline, so that's what you get. To prevent that, you need to escape it for sed, by passing it the string `\\n`. Since you have that in a double-quoted string on the command line, you need to add another backslash to escape it. (Or escape both backslashes; it doesn't matter here since in a double-quoted string, `\n` gives `\n`, so both `\\\n` and `\\\\n` end up as `\\n`.)

Also, you're missing the space to separate the first argument to printf from the second, so:

```
$ sed -e "1s|^|printf '%s\\\n' |" < file1
printf '%s\n' 'a 1-61' 'a 7134-7194'
```

Comment: @αғsнιη, `"\n"` in the shell ends up as `\n` passed to the command, and it's sed that changes that to a newline. See e.g. with `set -x` to see what gets passed to sed.

Comment: Ahh, I see, my bad, thanks

Comment: To ease the escaping, perhaps swap the quotes: `sed -e '1s|^|printf "%s\\n" |'`